# Creating a StringLike condition with Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I am trying to generate some terraform for an aws IAM policy. The condition in the policy looks like this

```
"StringLike": {
 "kms:EncryptionContext:aws:cloudtrail:arn": [
 "arn:aws:cloudtrail:*:aws-account-id:trail/*"
 ]
```

I am looking at the documentation for `aws_iam_policy_document`: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/iam_policy_document, but it's not clear to me as to how to write this in terraform. Any help would be greatly apprecaited. This is my attempt

```
condition {
        test = "StringLike"
        variable = "kms:EncryptionContext:aws:cloudtrail:arn"

        values = [
            "arn:aws:cloudtrail:*:aws-account-id:trail/*"
        ]
    }
```

Comment: Hey Evan, the syntax is definitely correct.

Comment: Did you see a specific error message when you tried what you showed in your question here? If so, it would be helpful to include that in the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hello Evan you logic is correct just to add :

Each document configuration may have one or more `statement`

```
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "example" {
  statement {
    actions = [
      "*", *//specify your actions here*
    ]

    resources = [
      "*", *//specify your resources here*
    ]
    condition {
     test = "StringLike"
     variable = "kms:EncryptionContext:aws:cloudtrail:arn"

     values = [
        "arn:aws:cloudtrail:*:aws-account-id:trail/*"
     ]
    }
}
```

Each policy statement may have zero or more condition blocks, which each accept the following arguments:

- `test` (Required) The name of the IAM condition operator to evaluate.
- `variable` (Required) The name of a Context Variable to apply the condition to. Context variables may either be standard AWS variables starting with aws:, or service-specific variables prefixed with the service name.
- `values` (Required) The values to evaluate the condition against. If multiple values are provided, the condition matches if at least one of them applies. (That is, the tests are combined with the "OR" boolean operation.)

**When multiple condition blocks are provided, they must all evaluate to true for the policy statement to apply. (In other words, the conditions are combined with the "AND" boolean operation.)**

Here's the REF from [terraform](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/iam_policy_document#condition)

IN Addition to create the policy from the document you created you  use it like this:

```
resource "aws_iam_policy" "example" {
  policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.example.json
}
```

Here's A ref from [Hashicorp](https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/terraform/aws-iam-policy?_ga=2.34714145.1211403764.1604928010-849963742.1587980996)